# ECS auto scaling with Capacity Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I am configuring an ECS auto scalling as the follow:
I have a cluster, cluster have a Capacity Provider
Capacity provider configured with the following:

```
Managed scaling Enabled
Target capacity 90 %
Managed termination protection Disabled
```

Capacity provider configured to use an Auto scale gorup,
Auto scale group name started with ECSManagedAutoScalingPolicy (As mentioned in AWS document)

and it contains the following:

```
Policy type:
Target tracking scaling
Enabled or disabled?
Enabled
Execute policy when:
As required to maintain metric CapacityProviderReservation (namespace: AWS/ECS/ManagedScaling, dimensions: CapacityProviderName = xxx-ctrlr-cp, ClusterName = xxx-cluster-xx, statistic: Average, unit: ) at 90
Take the action:
Add or remove capacity units as required
Instances need:
300 seconds to warm up before including in metric
Scale in:
Enabled
```

My question is:
Why the autoscale desired capacity change with itself ?
I set it to 2 and its turn to 4 or 6 (usually ends reaching the maximum capacity i set)
2- If its scaling out, based on cluster the cpu and ram utilization is very low, so why its decide to scale out, and how can i change the metrics?
[image]

Thank you, and sorry for the long post.